# When I try to run a Bespoken unit test, it can't find the filter file

Tags: unit-testing, alexa-skills-kit

When my directory contains these two files -

standard-handlers-unauthorized.test.yml

```
---
configuration:
  locales: en-US
  filter: mockGivenNameFilter.js

---
- test: Launch request
- LaunchRequest:
  - prompt: Welcome to Star Port 75 Travel.
                                How can I help you?
  - response.card.type: AskForPermissionsConsent
```

mockGivenNameFilter.js

```
module.exports = {
  onRequest: (test, requestEnvelope) => {
    // Removed contents to make it simpler. 
  }
};
```

- and I run this command -

```
bst test --jest.collectCoverage=false standard-handlers-unauthorized.test.yml
```

- I get this result, and I don't understand it -

```
Filter specified - but filter module not found at: mockGivenNameFilter.js
```

Comment: I was sure that if I moved to the version of BST that the writer of the book I'm reading was using, it would work.   But when I moved from version 2.6.7 to version 2.6.0, it still malfunctioned the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate the same error message, but I write this example maybe it could help you.

test.yml

```
---
configuration:
  locales: en-US
  filter: mockGivenNameFilter.js
---
- test : Test 1
- open weather score :
  - prompt :
    - "welcome I'm dragonfly"
- What is the weather score for seatle :
  - prompt: "*"
  - responseFiltered: "false"
  - response.card.type: "{mockGivenNameFilter}"
```

testing.json

```
{
  "platform": "alexa",
  "type": "e2e",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "virtualDeviceToken": "${VIRTUAL_DEVICE_TOKEN}",
  "voiceId": "Ivy",
  "trace": true,
  "asyncMode": true
}
```

mockGivenNameFilter.js

```
module.exports = {
    onRequest: (test, request) => {
        console.log('>>> onRequest: adding "requestFiltered" to the request. This prop will be added to request object.')
        request.requestFiltered = "true";
    },

    onResponse: (test, response) => {
        console.log('>>> onResponse: adding "responseFiltered" to the response. This prop will be added to response object.')
        response.responseFiltered = "true";
    },
    resolve: (variable, interaction) => {

        console.log('>>> resolve: resolving variable: ', variable)

        if (variable === 'mockGivenNameFilter') {
            console.log('>>> resolve: setting value for: ', variable)
            return 'custom value mockGivenNameFilter'
        }

        return null
    }
};
```

Reading a variable set on the response:

[image]

Reading a computed variable:

[image]

Hope it helps (-:

Comment: Thank you!   I gotta go work for the man, but tonight, I will try this!

Comment: I tried it, but it complained that I don't have a virtualDeviceToken.   Perhaps it's a Google thing, and not an Amazon thing?   Here's the error message I got: 

    A valid virtualDeviceToken property must be defined either in the testing.json or the YML test file under the config element

Comment: You need to change the "type" back to "unit" in the testing.json file and then you can remove the virtualDeviceToken - that is not required for unit tests.

Comment: That got me past that problem.   Then it complained that it couldn't find my interaction model. 

I'll wait till the weekend, take an example out of the book I'm reading ( Build Talking Apps - Craig Walls ) and dig into it. 

Maybe leaving this question around will affect my reputation negatively.   Shall I delete it?

Comment: I ended up inserting console logs into the installed Bespoken software.   The problem turned out to be that in Craig Walls' book, the require of the mocking software, nock, is outside of the export of the filter module.   When BST tries to "require" the filter module, it fails.   Solved that by putting the require of nock in the right place.   But then I had a host of other problems.   I'll just not do the BST parts, in the rest of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected version of the filter function.  The `const nock = require(...)` used to be outside of the `module.exports = {...}`.

After I fixed that though, I had a host of other problems.  I will avoid using BST in the rest of the book.  Example of "a host of problems" :

```
@Richards-MBP starport-75-user-info % bst test --jest.collectCoverage=false standard-handlers-authorized.test.yml

BST: v2.6.7  Node: v18.16.0
Use bst speak to interact directly with a Virtual Device via voice or chat

watchman warning:  Recrawled this watch 5 times, most recently because:
MustScanSubDirs UserDroppedTo resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/richard/work/230729/integration/starport-75-user-info' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/richardhedin/work/230729/integration/starport-75-user-info'`

 FAIL  test/unit/standard-handlers-authorized.test.yml
  ✕ Global

  ● Global

    Cannot find module 'lodash.set' from 'common.js'

      However, Jest was able to find:
        './common.js'
```